# On the "Collected Works" of Charles Bradfield Morrey, Jr

Tags: real-analysis, ho.history-overview, calculus-of-variations, biography

**Why [Charles Bradfield Morrey, Jr.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_B._Morrey_Jr.)'s "Collected works" haven't been published yet?**

I've been thinking of this question for a while, at least from the first time I started to improve the Wikipedia entry on him: I saw an advertising on this book on the back of the front page of the book [1] (as shown in the following image)

[image]

which, however, was published long ago. Note also that the other books advertised have been already published (or at least it was published a "Selecta"):

**Why I am interested in such a publication?**

Apart from the fact that I like (and sometimes I happily use in my job) mathematical analysis in its widest sense (i.e. including the machinery originating from it) and I'd use the informations in included in order to further improve Morrey's Wikipedia entry, the reason is that I have always been interested in the works of the masters (as advised by Abel) as a means of improving my knowledge and skills. My research approach could be described as "*build scientific research on its history (meant in its genetic sense)*": despite perhaps its non optimality, this approach has undoubtedly several advantages, the most evident being the ability to avoid the "rediscover of hot water". And as an Italian, I can say that I was favored in pursuing it by the fact that the Italian Mathematical Community is very active in the publication of the Collected/Selected works of noted Italian mathematicians (this is also a distinctive tract of the Polish, Russian and French Communities).
In particular, having being acquainted to Morrey's results by the reading of the works [2] (which was very difficult to find due to its relative rarity),  [3] and [4], and knowing about his work on quasiconformal maps from the large survey work written by Petru Caraman (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376187/looking-for-a-reference-on-conformal-mapping-on-bbb-rn/376213#376213) for the precise reference), I am curious to see if there are other interesting results and methods due to him, perhaps overshadowed by other more modern/fashionable methods.

**References**

[1] Gong, Sheng, *Integrals of Cauchy type on the ball*, (English), Cambridge, MA - Hong Kong: International Press Inc., pp. iii+304 (1993), [MR1337271](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1337271), [Zbl 0934.32004](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0934.32004).

[2] Morrey, Charles B. Jr. (1943), "Multiple integral problems in the calculus of variations and related topics", University of California Publications in Mathematics, (New Series), 1: 1–130, [MR 0011537](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0011537), [Zbl 0063.04107](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0063.04107).

[3] Morrey, Charles B. (1966), *Multiple integrals in the calculus of variations*, Die Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften, 130, Berlin–Heidelberg–New York: Springer-Verlag, pp. xii+506, ISBN 978-3-540-69915-6, [MR 0202511](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0202511), [Zbl 0142.38701](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0142.38701).

[4] Morrey, Charles B. Jr. (1968), "Partial Regularity Results for Non-Linear Elliptic Systems", Journal of Mathematics and Mechanics, 17 (7): 649–670, doi:[10.1512/iumj.1968.17.17041](https://doi.org/10.1512%2Fiumj.1968.17.17041), [MR 0237947](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0237947), [Zbl 0175.11901](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0175.11901).

Comment: this is likely a copyright issue.

Comment: Thanks @CarloBeenakker: so perhaps one (or more) of the publishers holding the rights of his publications has not yet given the permission to republish it. If this is true, it's a pity.