# Conformal maps between two given domains

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry, conformal-maps

Consider two domains
$$
\begin{aligned}
D_1&=\{x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n:x_n\leq 0\},\\
D_2&=\{x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n:x_n\leq \psi(x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1})\},
\end{aligned}
$$
where $ \psi:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\to\mathbb{R} $ is a smooth bounded function. I want to construct a conformal map $ \Phi:D_1\to D_2 $. I know that conformal maps between two arbitrary domains in high dimensional Euclidean space may not exist. Nevertheless here the domains are easy, I wonder if I can get such maps. If not, can I put more assumptions on it such that the result is true? Can you give me some hints or references?

Comment: The relevant theorem in this case is Liouville's (see this [fairly comprensive Q&A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376187/looking-for-a-reference-on-conformal-mapping-on-bbb-rn)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any conformal map in dimensions $\ge 3$ is necessary a superposition of inversions and isometries (see e.g. the link suggested by Daniele Tampieri in his comment), so it takes the boundary of $D_1$ to a hyperplane or (a part of) a sphere. Therefore, the graph of the  $\psi$ is a part of a sphere provided a conformal map exists.

Comment: Good point. (But a sphere isn't possible, so the graph of  must be a hyperplane.)